React-redux thunk causing weird loop behavior?
I'm having trouble using Redux in my React application. Some weird loop behavior occurs when dispatching a specific thunk action from within a useEffect inside a given component, even with an empty dependency array. I've dispatch this action elsewhere in the code, and works just fine.
I have a pointSlice which has a async action thunk called fetchPoints. Which basically, calls a method that makes use of a axios instance to make an API call:
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getPointsService } from "../../services/point/getPointForTeacher";

interface PointState {
  statusCode?: number;
  errors?: Array<any>;
  error?: boolean;
  data: Array<any>;
  status: "idle" | "loading" | "succeeded" | "failed";
}

const initialState: PointState = {
  data: [],
  status: "idle",
  error: false,
};

export const fetchPoints = createAsyncThunk(
  "point/fetchPoints",
  async (
    {
      id,
      month = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
      year = new Date().getFullYear(),
    }: fetchPointsProps,
    { rejectWithValue }
  ) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await getPointsService({ id, month, year });

      return data;
    } catch (err: any) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  }
);

const pointSlice = createSlice({
  name: "point",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchPoints.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(
        fetchPoints.fulfilled,
        (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
          state.status = "succeeded";
          state.data = action.payload;
        }
      )
      .addCase(
        fetchPoints.rejected,
        (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
          state.status = "failed";
        }
      );
  },
});

export default pointSlice.reducer;

And I have my filterSlice:
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  month: localStorage.getItem("filterYear") || new Date().getMonth() + 1,
  year: localStorage.getItem("filterYear") || new Date().getFullYear(),
  userId: "",
};

const filterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "filters",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setYearFilter(state, action: PayloadAction<number | string>) {
      state.year = action.payload;
    },
    setMonthFilter(state, action: PayloadAction<number | string>) {
      state.month = action.payload;
    },
    setUserIdFilter(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.userId = action.payload;
    },
    clearFilters(state) {
      state.month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
      state.year = new Date().getFullYear();
      state.userId = "";
      localStorage.removeItem("filterYear");
      localStorage.removeItem("filterMonth");
    },
    saveFilters(state) {
      localStorage.setItem("filterYear", state.year.toString());
      localStorage.setItem("filterMonth", state.month.toString());
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setYearFilter,
  setMonthFilter,
  setUserIdFilter,
  clearFilters,
  saveFilters,
} = filterSlice.actions;

export default filterSlice.reducer;

And my store configuration (trimmed imports):
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  themeConfig: themeConfigSlice,
  point: pointSlice,
  filters: filtersSlice,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

Don't bother too much with themeConfig, it's from the template I'm using for this project, called Vristo
Ok, so in my PointComponent, I'm dispatching fetchPoints inside a useEffect with empty array. While state.point.status is "loading" I return my Loader component, otherwise my CustomDataTable component, which is a modified copy of AltPagination from Vristo.
I'm injecting my data and other props, but most importantly I'm injecting the fetch method as refetch.
const Point = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  const { data, status, error } = useSelector(
    (state: IRootState) => state.point
  );

  const { userId, month, year } = useSelector(
    (state: IRootState) => state.filters
  );

  const fetch = () =>
    dispatch(
      fetchPoints({ id: "66a3fcc6f290e87b76d99795", month, year })
    );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
  }, []);

  return status === "loading" ? (
    <CustomLoader />
  ) : (
    <CustomDataTable
      pageTitle="Title"
      data={data}
      searchableItens={["date"]}
      refetch={fetch}
      columns={[...]}
      filterByMonth
      filterByYear
    />
  );
};

export default Point;

Here's how my CustomDataTable is structured (trimmed some blocks):
const CustomDataTable = ({
  data,
  columns,
  searchableItens,
  pageTitle,
  filterByYear = false,
  filterByMonth = false,
  onRowClick,
  refetch,
}: ICustomDataTableProps) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setPageTitle(pageTitle));
  });

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const PAGE_SIZES = [10, 20, 30, 50, 100];
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(PAGE_SIZES[0]);
  const [initialRecords, setInitialRecords] = useState(sortBy(data, "id"));
  const [recordsData, setRecordsData] = useState(initialRecords);

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [sortStatus, setSortStatus] = useState<DataTableSortStatus>({
    columnAccessor: "id",
    direction: "asc",
  });

  const currentDate = new Date();
  const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  // const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;

  const yearsToFilter = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => currentYear - i);

  // const [monthToFilter, setMonthToFilter] = useState(currentYear);
  // const [yearToFilter, setYearToFilter] = useState(currentMonth);

  const filters = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.filters);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(1);
  }, [pageSize]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const from = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const to = from + pageSize;
    setRecordsData([...initialRecords.slice(from, to)]);
  }, [page, pageSize, initialRecords]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInitialRecords(() => {
      if (data?.length > 0)
        return data?.filter((item) => {
          if (searchableItens) {
            let found = false;
            for (let searchable of searchableItens) {
              if (
                item?.[searchable]
                  ?.toString()
                  ?.toLowerCase()
                  ?.includes(search.toLowerCase())
              )
                found = true;
            }

            return found;
          }
        });

      return [];
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = sortBy(initialRecords, sortStatus.columnAccessor);
    if (data?.length > 0)
      setInitialRecords(
        sortStatus.direction === "desc" ? data.reverse() : data
      );
    setPage(1);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [sortStatus]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refetch) refetch();
  }, [filters]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="panel mt-6">
        <div className="flex md:items-center md:flex-row flex-col mb-5 gap-5">
          <h5 className="font-semibold text-lg dark:text-white-light">
            {pageTitle}
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div className="ltr:ml-auto rtl:mr-auto panel mt-6 gap-6 flex">
          {searchableItens && (
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-input w-auto"
              placeholder="Pesquisar..."
              value={search}
              onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
          )}

          {filterByMonth && (
            <select
              className="form-input w-auto"
              onChange={(e) =>
                dispatch(setMonthFilter(parseInt(e.target.value)))
              }
            >
              <option value="">Month</option>
              {...monthOptions}
            </select>
          )}

          {filterByYear && (
            <select
              className="form-input w-auto"
              onChange={(e) =>
                dispatch(setYearFilter(parseInt(e.target.value)))
              }
            >
              <option value="">Year</option>
              {yearsToFilter.map((year) => (
                <option key={year} value={year}>
                  {year}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="datatables">
          <DataTable
            records={recordsData}
            columns={columns}
            totalRecords={initialRecords.length}
            recordsPerPage={pageSize}
            page={page}
            onPageChange={(p) => setPage(p)}
            recordsPerPageOptions={PAGE_SIZES}
            onRecordsPerPageChange={setPageSize}
            sortStatus={sortStatus}
            onSortStatusChange={setSortStatus}
            onRowClick={onRowClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomDataTable;

Bottomline, what's the idea here? The idea is:
Fetch points, inject in my data table;
If user changes year or month selected option in CustomDataTable, dispatch an update to the filters;
With filters updated, set my useEffect in motion;
Do we have a refetch method? If so, call it;
And the refetch method is just a dispatch of fetchPoints, same as step one, used in my Point component.
Thing is, this doesn't work as expected.
It's recursively making API calls. But again, only for refetch.
And I don't even have to change year or month. It gets stuck in this loop of loading/calling fetchPoints right away.
For now, this is what I've tried so far:
Set my useEffect with an empty dependency array. Should run only once, right? Yeah, but no. Gives me the same behavior. As if the function is calling itself.
I've also tried to make use of useCallback instead.
Instead of dispatching my action directly from onChange events in select, making use of useState, and feeding them into the dependency array.
Instead of refetch={fetch}, refetch={() => fetch()}

FWIW I don't see any recursive code or logic in the code you have shared. Seems more likely you have some render-looping issue. Are you seeing the useEffect hook's fetch being called over and over, or is the table component calling fetch over and over? I think you should do a bit of debugging investigation first to isolate where your issue is and come back and [edit] your post to focus on just that part of the code and report your findings.

Hi, Drew. Thanks for the answer and formatting.
useEffect in CustomDataTable being called over and over, not only refetch method.
But if I remove refetch call, then no looping, Even If I have more logic inside my useEffect.
With refetch, looping starts even with an empty dependency array. But, as yourself have stated, no recursion either in fetchPoints or it's implementation in refetch. I'm finding it very weird.
I will sure look more into it and edit my post with my findings :)

Hard to say without a minimum reproducible example. But I would say that is very likely that somehow the filters ref changes after each fetch and therefore this is executed endlessly in CustomDataTable.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (refetch) refetch();
  }, [filters]);

Keep in mind that the redux state is immutable and a brand new state is returned after each update no matter how minor it is. So if you change anything in the filters state the useEffect will be retriggered.
To check if this is the case try removing the filters from the dependency array.
If this doesn't work please try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Also as a side-note, it looks like you have quite a few useEffects in CustomDataTable so you might want to check if you need them all and if all the dependency arrays are needed. Additionaly the first useEffect (the one with dispatch(setPageTitle(pageTitle));) doesn't have a dependency array so is executed on each re-render

Hi, Berci. First of all, thanks for your answer.
Filter state doesn't get touched by any part of the code other than to be updated onChange event of the selects for year and month. It doesn't or shouldn't be whenever dispatching fetchPoints action either.
As I've stated, I did try with an empty dependency array, got the same behaviour.
Dependency array with useState intermediaries instead of filters directly. Same.
Tks for the heads up for the first useEffect, Vristo's default. Haven't touched that part.
I'll look into providing a minimal, rerproducible example a soon as I can.

Issue
Sounds like something is remounting repeatedly. I see that Point conditionally renders the CustomDataTable component based on the loading state that the dispatched fetchPoints action updates.
It would appear that when CustomDataTable mounts it does a few things:

Point conditionally renders CustomDataTable based on the state.point.status value, which is initially false
const { data, status, error } = useSelector(
  (state: IRootState) => state.point
);

...

return status === "loading" ? (
  <CustomLoader />
) : (
  <CustomDataTable
    pageTitle="Title"
    data={data}
    searchableItens={["date"]}
    refetch={fetch}
    columns={[...]}
    filterByMonth
    filterByYear
  />
);


CustomDataTable selects the filter state
const filters = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.filters);


CustomDataTable runs a side-effect to refetch data under two conditions

The useEffect runs because the component mounted
refetch is truthy so it is called

useEffect(() => {
  if (refetch) refetch();
}, [filters]);


Calling refetch which dispatches fetchPoints in Point and triggers the state.point.status state update and unmounts and mounts CustomDataTable.


This creates the render-loop condition where you see fetch called over and over again.
Solution Suggestion
I'd suggest refactoring the Point component to conditionally render the loading indicator based on the status and conditionally render CustomDataTable on data being available. Initially when state.point.data is undefined, CustomDataTable won't be rendered until data is fetched, then later is will remain mounted while refetches occur.
Example:
const Point = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  const { data, status, error } = useSelector(
    (state: IRootState) => state.point
  );

  const { userId, month, year } = useSelector(
    (state: IRootState) => state.filters
  );

  const fetch = () =>
    dispatch(
      fetchPoints({ id: "66a3fcc6f290e87b76d99795", month, year })
    );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {status === "loading" && <CustomLoader />}
      {data && (
        <CustomDataTable
          pageTitle="Title"
          data={data}
          searchableItems={["date"]}
          refetch={fetch}
          columns={[...]}
          filterByMonth
          filterByYear
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

Update CustomDataTable to not call refetch when it mounts, but rather when the filters are updated.

Remove the useEffect hook call in CustomDataTable that calls refetch

Call refetch in the handlers when updating filters state, e.g.
onChange={(e) => {
  dispatch(setMonthFilter(parseInt(e.target.value)));
  if (refetch) refetch();
}}



const CustomDataTable = ({
  data,
  columns,
  searchableItems,
  pageTitle,
  filterByYear = false,
  filterByMonth = false,
  onRowClick,
  refetch,
}: ICustomDataTableProps) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setPageTitle(pageTitle));
  }, [dispatch, pageTitle]); // <-- add correct dependency array!

  ... this logic unchanged

  // Removed "if (refetch) refetch();" effect

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="panel mt-6">
        ...

        <div className="ltr:ml-auto rtl:mr-auto panel mt-6 gap-6 flex">
          ...

          {filterByMonth && (
            <select
              className="form-input w-auto"
              onChange={(e) => {
                dispatch(setMonthFilter(parseInt(e.target.value)));
                if (refetch) refetch(); // <--
              }}
            >
              <option value="">Month</option>
              {...monthOptions}
            </select>
          )}

          {filterByYear && (
            <select
              className="form-input w-auto"
              onChange={(e) => {
                dispatch(setYearFilter(parseInt(e.target.value)));
                if (refetch) refetch(); // <--
              }}
            >
              <option value="">Year</option>
              {yearsToFilter.map((year) => (
                <option key={year} value={year}>
                  {year}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          )}
        </div>

        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

